# SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities using SeleniumGrid with GeckoDriver Firefox through Java

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, geckodriver

Below code I written to open www.google.com under selenium standalone Grid environment. During the execution it shows error

**CONFIGURATION:**

- OS: WINDOWS 10
- BROWSER : FireFox (66.0.3)
- Selenium Standalone Command:

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\eClipse\jar\Selenium\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role standalone
  ```

**ERROR:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'QAT2', ip: '10.1.6.79', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I try to google this exception but not find any clue to solve it. Can I    have any solution for this.

**CODE:**

```
public class GridSetup {

private String baseUrl ;
private String nodeURL ;
public WebDriver wDriver ; 

public static void main() throws MalformedURLException{
baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
nodeURL = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";    
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\eClipse    \\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();       
System.out.println( "#####################");
caps.setBrowserName("firefox");
caps.setCapability("marioneete", true);
caps.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
caps.setVersion("66.0.3");

wDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), caps);
wDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wDriver.get(baseUrl);
} 

}
```

Comment: Any one solution for this...?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' 
System info: host: 'QAT2', ip: '10.1.6.79', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91' 
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.141.59**.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_91** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u91* , *Selenium Client v3.141.59*.

---

### Solution

Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u202**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).